# Add the source of the information in image

Tags: border

How can I add the font in the image footer and a top-of-the-line description?
[image]

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: \caption is usually  used for the top part, a blank line under the table Al ng with the text for the rest.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

the package `copyrightbox` is dedicated for notes to images positioned below, left or right of images:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \caption{Figure caption}
\copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{example-image}}%
                {Source: \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```